# I don't receive notifications

Tags: bug, comment, notifications

A user sent me several notifications in the comments of [this discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/109432/proving-some-properties-of-expected-first-order-statistics-with-respect-to-sampl) today, but I have not received any notification.

Comment: Maybe this is a bug. At least according to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125208/when-exactly-do-i-get-comment-notifications) thread you should have got notified. Did you get notified now?

Comment: @AndreSilva Yes I did. And I also get the latest notification from the user 1h ago.

Comment: I notice you responded to all those pings within five minutes, suggesting you were monitoring the comment thread.  Perhaps the system recognized that and considered you notified.

Comment: @whuber: that's possible, indeed the page was always open in my browser

Comment: Ooo, I think this is a bug around comment replies that are added during a comment edit; will check on it tomorrow.